# Couchbase - Upsert JSON in a list of JSON based on a condition

Tags: python, couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to do a complex operation on Couchbase(Capella) which actually tries to upsert a JSON inside an array. So, if JSON with a condition key-value already exists we need to update the entire JSON, else we need to insert. I have referred to the support docs and formed the query which succeeds but doesn't update or insert the JSON. Could you help me correct this?

```
UPDATE stash.pso.all_items AS im
SET im.items = CASE WHEN (ANY v IN im.items SATISFIES v.code = "2118001" END)
                                THEN
                                      ARRAY (CASE WHEN v.code = "2118001" THEN {"code": "2118001", "price": 1.1} ELSE v END)
                                      FOR v IN im.items END
                                ELSE
                                    ARRAY_APPEND(im.items, {"code": "2118001", "price": 1.1})
                                END
WHERE im.shop_id = "2022-11-18-516";
```

I've also read the docs and see there is a function `mutate_in` which helps us with the python SDK. If mutate_in is the best approach, please help upsert using the mutate_in function.

Example doc:

```
{
  "email": "appdemo@---.com",
  "fresh": true,
  "items": [{"code": "311001", "price": 1.3}, {"code": "6118001", "price": 1.1}]
  "revised": 0,
  "shop_id": "2022-11-18-516"
}
```

Comment: Yes this sounds like it will be possible with mutate_in - please see the documentation for details on upserting JSON: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/howtos/subdocument-operations.html#mutating